# Can someone else take my old name after I change it?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I am worried that when I change my name during game (using shift>tab>settings), even if for a short while, someone else can take my original name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Technically, they can take your name whenever they want. Your name in Team Fortress 2 is equal to your Steam profile name, and there's never been any restriction on how many people can share a single Steam name. My own name is a common English word and I share it with dozens of other profiles.

In short, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: However, if more than one person has the same name (including spaces), the game server will append (#) after it, where # is a number.